Psalm 88: does it apply to the New Testament's Christian God?
I was reading Psalm 88:

1 Lord, you are the God who saves me; day and night I cry out to you.
2 May my prayer come before you; turn your ear to my cry.
3 I am overwhelmed with troubles and my life draws near to death.
4 I am counted among those who go down to the pit; I am like one without strength.
5 I am set apart with the dead, like the slain who lie in the grave, whom you remember no more,
who are cut off from your care.
6 You have put me in the lowest pit, in the darkest depths.
7 Your wrath lies heavily on me; you have overwhelmed me with all your waves.
8 You have taken from me my closest friends and have made me repulsive to them.
I am confined and cannot escape;
9 my eyes are dim with grief.I call to you, Lord, every day; I spread out my hands to you.
10 Do you show your wonders to the dead? Do their spirits rise up and praise you?
11 Is your love declared in the grave, your faithfulness in Destruction?
12 Are your wonders known in the place of darkness, or your righteous deeds in the land of oblivion?
13 But I cry to you for help, Lord; in the morning my prayer comes before you.
14 Why, Lord, do you reject me and hide your face from me?
15 From my youth I have suffered and been close to death; I have borne your terrors and am in despair.
16 Your wrath has swept over me; your terrors have destroyed me.
17 All day long they surround me like a flood; they have completely engulfed me.
18 You have taken from me friend and neighbor— darkness is my closest friend.

I was left wondering and had conflicting thoughts.
Question: Is the God that this psalm refers to the same God as our Christian God, i.e. Christ's father in heaven? I am asking because this psalm projects an image of a God that abandons his children and could care less about them being fruitful and having support etc., which is not the "Heavenly Father" image that we have in the New Testament.
Do we Christians read the Old Testament as a historical artifact only, or more than that?

Psalm 22 John 16:32 Yeah, reading over the quoted Psalm 88 verses, I was thinking of Psalm 22, which Jesus quoted while he was on the cross (Mark 15:34, Matt 27:46)

this can't be much more than an opinion question because it assumes an opinion without identifying a teaching authority.  If you want to ask a concrete question, which is the only kind of question we deal with here, you'd have to identify which Christian sects actually believe there is a different God in the Old Testament.  You could ask about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcionism But you can't much ask about the thoughts of modern Christians here at least, because you're just asking for personal biblical interpretation.

Wee some of the related questions on the right-hand side.  like this one https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/18024/how-does-the-catholic-church-deal-with-the-differences-between-the-god-described?rq=1  (it's not a fantastic example since it is not really tied down to a denomination) But the wording is what we're looking for. "how does X deal with ..." is a concrete question.

@PeterTurner With all due respect I refuse what you said, there is not a single place where I was exerting an opinion. I am Maronite Catholic, have nothing to do with Marcionism, for me it is the same God in the old and new testament, hence why this question was asked, since the psalmist is talking to God that 'projects' (focus on the word projects which means 'makes it seems like') is a different God- ie like if it is not Christ's father - that he is praying to, hence I reached out for assistance here. My question is simple, has no hidden agendas and is valid from a believer's perspective.

@ccot, that's fantastic, but that idea that the God of the OT is different than the God of the NT is why I brought up Marcionism.   This site isn't about getting an individual believer's perspective, it is about getting a Church's teaching.  So that's why we closed the question. It seems unlikely that you're going to find a church today which espouses Marcionism, so the better question to ask here is the one I linked, which was already asked.  You could adapt it for Maronite Catholicism as opposed to Latin, but I don't think the answer would be much different.

You asked two questions, one of them probably overly broad, but I'll reply (at least briefly) to both.

Is the God that this psalm refers to the same God as our Christian God, i.e. Christ's father in heaven?

Yes. As Eliel noted, simply being Christian doesn't grant some sort of magical immunity to despair. Indeed, Christ Himself tasted separation from God as He hung on the cross! Despair is one of the adversary's weapons which he will use in attempting to draw believers away, and it shouldn't be surprising that one might experience such "reminders" of how we are lost without God's Grace.
What the psalmist is experiencing is the despair of being apart from God; that is, the psalm is describing the condition of unbelievers, which is very much still the case for those who do not have Christ. What is not recorded (at least in this psalm) is God's reply.
As Eliel noted, the Psalms are widely regarded as good models for prayer, but I believe they also serve to show those who might be struggling that they are not alone in their trials.
The true "punishment" awaiting unbelievers is complete separation from God, and Psalm 88 gives us a taste of that. It does not follow, however, that God abandons His true children, and indeed there are many psalms of rejoicing to be found even in the same book.

Do we Christians read the Old Testament as a historical artifact only, or more than that?

The primary purpose of the Old Testament is to point to Christ. It also serves as a history (a true history, from Genesis 1 onward), focused on Israel, and as an illustration of how God interacted with His Creation prior to Christ. Importantly, it teaches us where we came from, and why Creation is in the condition it's in (namely, due to Adam and Eve and the Fall).
The Old Testament teaches us about God, tells us (all of us, not just Jews) where we came from and why we need a Savior, and lays the foundation for the New Testament. Most Christians would argue it isn't strictly necessary (that is, one can be a Christian without ever reading the Old Testament... or the New Testament, for that matter, so long as one has heard and believed the basic message), but it serves as the backdrop which explains the "why" of many things relevant to the believer. I would further argue that Genesis 1-11 in particular are important as they apply to all people.
Even so, note 2 Timothy 3:16-17:

16All Scripture is breathed out by God and profitable for teaching, for reproof, for correction, and for training in righteousness, 17that the man of God may be complete, equipped for every good work.

While we believe this includes the New Testament, it certainly includes the Old Testament, and the author may have had the Old Testament particularly in mind when writing these words. Books such as Proverbs and Psalms in particular are widely held as being full of wisdom and insight.

The Psalm does not describe God as "a God that abandons his children and could care less about them being fruitful and having support etc.", since it does not say the response that the psalmist obtained to the prayer he was making to God. (In fact, the first verse, "you are the God who saves me", contradicts this.)
Rather, it is about the psalmist expressing his own inner emotions, how he felt at that moment.
Servants of God are not exempt from feeling negative emotions. This Psalm is a good example of how we should pray to God when we need his help.

Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I had to downvote this answer. How does the psalm's basis thesis:  "Lord, you are the God who saves me" not describe God? Many psalms do not include a response from God.

@DanFefferman, I'm pretty sure that isn't what Eliel is saying. I fixed it for you; please take another look.

Like Job, the psalmists often expressed their complaints to God and cried to him for deliverance. This kind of psalm is known as a lament, and there are many of them, including Psalms 3, 4, 5, 7, 9-10, 13, 14, 17, 22, 25, 26, 27, 28, 31, 36, 39, 40:12-17, 41-43, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 59, 61, 64, 70, 71, 77, 86, 89, 120, 139, 141, 142.
And yes, they do apply to the Christian God. When Jesus said "My God, My God, why have you forsaken me?" he was quoting the beginning of Psalm 22. And of course, he was talking to the same God that both Christians and Jews believe in.

My God, my God, why have you forsaken me?
Why so far from my call for help,
from my cries of anguish?  My God, I call by day, but you do not answer;
by night, but I have no relief.

Psalm 88 is more unrelenting in its complaint that Psalm 22 but we should not lose sight of its primary message, stated in the opening verse: "Lord, you are the God who saves me; day and night I cry out to you."  The Bible is replete with examples of these plaintive cries - from  Moses to King David, from Job to Jesus in the Garden of Gethsemane. God may seem to abandon us at times, but if we continue to call out to him with a sincere heart, God will eventually respond. Indeed, as the psalms show, God wants us to express our problems to him in this way when we need to:
Psalm 34

17 The righteous cry out, and the Lord hears them;
he delivers them from all their troubles. 18 The Lord is close to the brokenhearted
and saves those who are crushed in spirit.

Conclusion: The Psalms must definitely NOT be read as mere historical artifacts. Christians have every right to share their difficulties with God, including their feelings of abandonment by him. Jesus himself did so. While some psalms do seem outdated (thinking here of those that ask God to harm our enemies) most of them are perfectly relevant to us today, including laments such as this one. By coincidence, a friend gave me The Case for the Psalms by N. T. Wright earlier today. I'm just starting it, but even so, I am going to recommend it for further reading on the subject.

Q: Do we Christians read the Old Testament as a historical artifact only, or more than that?
For the first 1,500 years of the Christian church's existence, the book of Psalms was the most read, studied, meditated upon, and prayed over book in the Bible. For the small proportion of people who could read, their prized possession was likely a Psalter or a Book of Hours, a book filled with prayers, many of them excerpts of the Psalms.
Shortly before I became a Christian, I read Psalm 23, "The Lord is my shepherd...". It played a role in my becoming a Christian. A few years later, I struggled with frequent terrible nightmares. I began to meditate on the Psalms much more (as well as Isaiah), and the nightmares went away. Thus my experience is the same as that of the early church: Psalms is one of the first and best places for Christians to turn when their heart is filled with trouble.
Q: Is the God that this psalm refers to the same God as our Christian God, i.e. Christ's father in heaven?
Yes. There are many Psalms that have prophecies of the coming of Jesus Christ. Jesus quoted Psalm 22 while he hung on the cross. Many other Psalms are quoted by the Gospel writers. Jesus in Matthew 22 quoted Psalm 101 specifically to deal with the idea that the Messiah had a special relationship to God:
41 Now while the Pharisees were gathered together, 
Jesus asked them a question, 42 saying, 
“What do you think about the Christ? Whose son is he?”
They said to him, “The son of David.” 
43 He said to them, “How is it then that David, in the Spirit, 
calls him Lord, saying,

44 “‘The Lord said to my Lord,
“Sit at my right hand,
    until I put your enemies under your feet”’?

45 If then David calls him Lord, how is he his son?” 
46 And no one was able to answer him a word, 
nor from that day did anyone dare to ask him any more questions.

If Jesus uses the Psalms to establish his identity prophetically, then surely they speak of the same God as his Father.
The Psalm you quote has many similarities with themes in the Book of Job, as well as ideas from Ecclesiastes:

Whatever your hand finds to do, do it with your might, for there is no
work or thought or knowledge or wisdom in Sheol, to which you are
going. - Ecclesiastes 9:10

Job is filled with analogies to the suffering servant and pleas to God for salvation, where he (like the man in Psalm 88:4) denies having any strength left to save himself:
11 What is my strength, that I should wait?
    And what is my end, that I should be patient?
12 Is my strength the strength of stones, or is my flesh bronze?
13 Have I any help in me,
    when resource is driven from me?
Job 6:11-13

In Matthew, Jesus is called greater than Solomon (who wrote Ecclesiastes) who was called the wisest man who ever lived. All these connections point to Psalm 88 being a fruitful poem to read, meditate upon for wisdom, and be healed by.
